# Как перенести div в конец?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Имеется структура

```
<div id="slideInner">
        <div class="slide" id="slide1">
         <img src="img/fon1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide2"> 
          <img src="img/fon2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide3">
          <img src="img/fon3.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Как перенести div id slide1 в конец, а из начала удалить?
Я пишу следующее, но ничего не получается. Подскажите, где ошибка и как правильно все это организовать?

```
$("#slideInner").eq(0).clone().appendTo("#slideInner"); 
$("#slideInner").eq(0).remove()
```

Comment: Клонировать зачем? Всего одна строка:

    $('#slide1').appendTo('#slideInner');

Comment: Мне надо динамически удалять первый слайд и добовлять в конец, чтобы было зацикливание.
_____

Как это сделать?

Comment: > мне надо динамически удалять первый слайд

@harley, Поздравляю. Код я вам показал.

Comment: Ну, так-то да, но вы обратились конкретно к id-слайду. А мне надо, чтобы он выбирал первый элемент без привязки к id. Чтобы то же самое можно было сделать и со вторым слайдом, и третим. При нажатии соответствующих кнопок
\
____

Где здесь ошибка $("#slideInner").eq(0).clone().appendTo("#slideInner"); $("#slideInner").eq(0).remove() ?

Comment: @harley, а селектор правильно указать - не судьба? [Смотрите пример][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/7ne7xst1/

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
$('#slideInner > div:first').remove().appendTo('#slideInner');
```

Comment: @mountpoint, драсьце.... приехали. Я только что в коментах показал.

Comment: @Deonis, ваш код работает только для дива с айди slide1. А мой универсальный, то есть для циклических операций, как нужно автору.

Comment: @mountpoint, он работает для всех, если правильно указать селектор и пример, я имел в виду, в последним комментарием. Но даже не в этом дело, remove - зачем? Просто на всякий случай?

Comment: @Deonis, вы читаете, что автор пишет?

>>Как перенести div id slide1 в конец а из начала удалить?

Comment: Спасибо большое. Еще два вопроса, почему не нужно удаление. Ведь если мы добавляем в конец div-s через append, то получается, у нас должно увеличиваться количество div-в.

Comment: @mountpoint, а вы разве заметили, [что он остается вначале][1]?

P.S. 

> то получается у нас должно увеличиваться количество div-в

Не получается и ничего не увеличивается. Если бы увеличивалось, то вы бы это наблюдали.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/7ne7xst1/

Comment: Извините, что нарываюсь опять, не могу второй вопрос сформулировать, чтобы не показать весь участок кода. Я могу связаться с вами через скайп или аську, чтобы уточнить один момент и показать на примере, как работает код, он у меня только на локальном компе, в интернете нет...

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант вроде лаконичнее.

```
$("#slideInner").append( $("#slide1") );
```